# c malloc in other function and structs

Tags: c

Im having problems with c and pointers. I keep grinding on this and it has to be easy. I have a struct and I allocate in one function, then pass the pointer back to the original function. But when I try to fill the values of the struct with other variables, and then print them or copy them , the app segfaults saying the memory address is out of bounds.

```
struct memcache_buffer{
        int  elements, action;
        char keys[MAX_KEYS], values[MAX_KEYS], returns[MAX_KEYS]; //action 0 = delete , 1 = get 2 = set
}memcache_buffer;

struct memcache_buffer* memcache_allocate_buffer(int size){
        struct memcache_buffer *buffer;
        buffer =malloc(sizeof(struct memcache_buffer));
        return buffer;
}

void memcache_set(char * key, char * value){
        pthread_t process_t;
        struct memcache_buffer *buffer=memcache_allocate_buffer(1);
        char keys,values;
        buffer->elements = 1;
        buffer->action=2;
        //printf("crash?\n");
        printf("%s %s",key,value);
        snprintf(buffer->keys[0],KEY_SIZE,"%s",key);
        snprintf(buffer->values[0],VALUE_SIZE,"%s",value);
        pthread_create(&process_t,NULL,memcache_process,buffer);
}
```

am I allocating the memory right? allocating memory and these pointers are sure rough, especially only messing with php in the past.

Comment: Did you use `valgrind` to debug memory leaks? Did you compile with all warnings enabled? What book did you read on C programming? Your pastebin is not a complete code, so we can't really help. (Are `key` and `value` correct?)

Comment: At what lie do you see a segfault?

Comment: id 2nd use of valgrind - having recently learnt to use memcheck and massif i would say that they are a crucial tool for C development

Comment: #0  _IO_vsnprintf (string=0xffffffd8 <Address 0xffffffd8 out of bounds>, maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x28e4e7 "%s", 
    args=0xbffeb4fc "8\304\t\bȵ\t\b\020<\022") at vsnprintf.c:118
#1  0x00304a73 in __snprintf (s=0xffffffd8 <Address 0xffffffd8 out of bounds>, maxlen=20, format=0x28e4e7 "%s") at snprintf.c:35
#2  0x0027b74b in memcache_set (key=0x809c438 "dbmidnr_test10", value=0x809e5d8 "15") at /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:65
#3  0x0027b838 in memcache_sid (username=0xbffebb88 "test10", id=0xf) at dm_memcache.c:118

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
struct memcache_buffer{
    char keys[MAX_KEYS], values[MAX_KEYS]
}

snprintf(buffer->keys[0],KEY_SIZE,"%s",key);
                     ^^^
snprintf(buffer->values[0],VALUE_SIZE,"%s",value);
                       ^^^
```

Drop the `[0]` or `snprintf` will try to dereference some bogus value.

Comment: A compiler should have warned you, if you enable all warnings and use a good enough compiler (GCC, Clang, ...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In my opinions compilers should have warnings for this stuff enabled by default.

Comment: Agreed, but some compilers don't, and some newbies don't ask for all warnings, or ignore them.

Comment: But what happens when I have multiple keys. Then about not posting the full code, Theres not enough room for all of dbmail on this post. I will paste bin the full code for the functions I am adding. Theres alot there. What book did I read? I read learn c in 24 hours by sams, like 15 years ago and I have been using google and stack overflow for the past week learning all this stuff. I am not a c programmer.

Comment: It probably did warn me about the problem but when compiling the whole app its hard to want to go thru 100 screens of gcc messages

Comment: Iv also been trying to use DDD but it seems really buggy, it only stops at my break points 10% of the time.

Comment: code blocks, I dont know how to import a whole gnu project into the IDE. Is there a easy way or do I have to add everything by hand and everything. Theres alot here.

Comment: out of interest, what sort of set of compiler warning options are people thinking would be suitable, might be useful to paste in for guidance? (i'd be keen to see those for gcc)

Comment: @Hiett `-Wall -Wextra`. Optionally `-pedantic` if you aim for portability.

Comment: @cnicutar - thanks, i've been using -Wall but not -Wextra, may add that to my makefile - is pednatic the one that insists all your variable declaraions are at the top of the file and things like that, maybe a good one to use if you want to port to MSVC (from gcc)?

Comment: @Hiett That's right, but you should also consider selecting a dialect via `-std=...`, for example `-std=c99`.

Comment: https://github.com/skrapsrwt/dbmail-memcache - this is all the code. The changes I made are in src/dm_memcache.c and src/dm_db.c . I'm trying to cache all the users information on a memcache server to cut the load from the mysql server. Then I feel it will be great for a cloud setup, when more servers are spun up they will be able to access the cache for user information. Then possibly add mail caching also. but I am unsure how to do that exactly just of yet. I'm still trying to get this small peice working right. The idea is to be able to set arrays of keys and values then a worker thread ..

Comment: I rewrote it like 5 times this week, once I even had a global buffer with locks and mutexes and stuff, but then soon relized that if more than 1 person accessed it that way then they would all be racing to get and set the buffer and that would cause problems, a bottle neck.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. I set it like that so I can have X amount of character strings in the struct.  What do I need to do? I'm only using snprint to trunc the input beofre sending it to the memcache server anyways.

Comment: @CraigSparks - "what happens when I have multiple keys.." i think that looking at that struct you can't have multiple keys as char keys[MAX_KEYS] represents one string only, maybe you need an array of strings, e.g. char **keys, not char *keys?